# permissions option in mount ntfs

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab, ntfs

I recently read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91054/828892) about mounting NTFS partitions in linux, so that I can change file and folder permissions (chmod). And they explain that I use the option "permissions". Example:

```
# fstab
UUID=12102C02102CEB83 /mount_point  ntfs-3g  defaults,permissions 0 0

# manual
sudo mount /dev/sdax -t ntfs-3g -o permissions /mount_point
```

And works, but i checked [man fstab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) and [man mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) and couldn't find the option "permissions". Search internet and in [few places mention it](https://wiki.epfl.ch/icit/kb/linux-mount-ntfs-with-permissions), but without link to the source

Can someone tell me where this option comes from? (Provide an official link explaining this option). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `ntfs-3g` has its own manual page available [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g).

In particular:

> **permissions**: Set standard permissions on created files and use standard access control. This option is set by default when a user mapping file is present.